# NEO4J CYPHER Query to Group By a Sorted Query

Tags: collections, group-by, neo4j, cypher

I am having a hard time coming up with the right CYPHER query for a use case:

I have `USER` and `HOBBY` as nodes. `Comment` is relationship on `User`'s `Hobbies`. `User` can have many `Hobbies` and other `Users` can `COMMENT` on `Hobbies` of  `User`.

Problem: Show the `HOBBIES` and `COMMENTS` with latest `Comments` for a `User` sorted by the most recent ones.

The query I am trying to perform is:

```
MATCH (u:user)-[r:comment]->(n:Hobby) 
    WHERE has(r.`comment`) and u.id = 'Test' 
RETURN 
    DISTINCT n.id,n.name, n.description, COLLECT(r.id) as `comment` 
ORDER BY 
    r.creationdate DESC
```

Apparently, `r.creationdate` can't be used to sort within a grouped result. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Can comments be replied to meaning comment on a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need distinct in your case, aggregation already makes distinct

`r` doesn't exist anymore at the point where you want to sort it.

1. Either you don't collect, then you can sort by it,
2. or you sort it upfront with `WITH`.
3. or you sort by `min(r.creationdate)` or `max(r.creationdate)`

for number 2:

```
MATCH (u:user)-[r:comment]->(n:Hobby) 
    WHERE has(r.`comment`) and u.id = 'Test' 
WITH
    n, r.id as rid 
ORDER BY 
    r.creationdate DESC
RETURN n.id,n.name, n.description, collect(rid) as comment
```

for number 3:

```
MATCH (u:user)-[r:comment]->(n:Hobby) 
    WHERE has(r.`comment`) and u.id = 'Test' 
RETURN 
    DISTINCT n.id,n.name, n.description, COLLECT(r.id) as `comment`, max(r.creationdate)
ORDER BY 
    max(r.creationdate) DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try imposing order before aggregation. How about

```
MATCH (u:user {id:'test'})-[r:comment]->(n:Hobby)
WHERE has(r.comment)
WITH n, r
  ORDER BY r.creationdate
RETURN n.id, n.name, n.description, COLLECT(r.id) as comment
```

---

(Sidenote: I'd recommend 'idiomatic' or at least consistent *style* for your queries, i.e. type labels like you would your name (`(:User)`) and relationship types as if you were shouting on the internet (`[:COMMENT]`). This makes no difference for validity or performance, but it's just nice and it helps avoid silly mistakes to follow even arbitrary conventions.)